# select specific text on page and remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is is possible to select specific text string on the page directly without a id, class, etc...

I have this text string "ERROR: AffiliateID invalid" that I would like to remove from the page.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175775/find-all-instances-of-old-in-a-webpage-and-replace-each-with-new-using-a-jav - this may help you

Comment: Do you have *any* idea as to which element contains the text? Even just the nested position of the element on the page? Something so that the text can be targeted directly?

Comment: Funny because it appears before the <head> tag when looking at the source in FF------>

ERROR: AffiliateID invalid
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should solve the problem imho:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( /ERROR: AffiliateID invalid/g, "");
```

The code replaces all occurences of the string with empty string.

**EDIT:** Use it only if you're 100 percent positive that it won't break your HTML in any way.

**EDIT 2:**

I don't know about a specific jQuery function for this. I found this tip:

1) http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/6-quick-jquery-tips-text-manipulation-timers-and-elements.html

> Remove a word with jQuery
>
> The simple way – using regular expressions:
>
> var el = $('#id');
>      el.html(el.html().replace(/word/ig, ""));

The example uses the same [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function as the version in pure javascript. The function comes from JavaScript 1.2 (the standard that is 10 years old and is implemented in all major browsers). So I guess there's no reason to use a function from jQuery.

2) There is a [plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/) for replacing text in specified HTML tags. Maybe it is worth trying.

Comment: This works perfect. I take it it is a javascript version. Jquery version of the same? Also is there a way to put that text in an alert box and then remove it?