# Bookmarklet Help: Creating a Find/Replace Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, replace, bookmarklet

I'm trying to slightly modify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1175775/553663) so that it prompts for the text to search for, followed by the text to replace with, and when all done processing, show a dialog box letting me know it's done.

I plan to use it on a phpmyadmin database edit page that'll have any number of textboxes filled with text (*which is what I need it to search and replace in*). Also, the text to search for and replace may or may not be multi-line, so I've added the 'm' param in the regex, and also, since I'll be doing searches/replaces that may contain html, they'll often have quotes/double quotes in them. ex:

Search for:

```
<img height="76" width="92" src="http://www.gifs.net/Animation11/Hobbies_and_Entertainment/Games_and_Gambling/Slot_machine.gif" /></div>
<div class="rtecenter"> <strong><em><font color="#ff0000">Vegas Baby!<br />
</font></em></strong></div>
```

and maybe replace with nothing (*just to erase all that code*), or some other html. So far this is the bookmarklet I've come up with, (*javascript, and especially bookmarklets aren't something I mess with often*) however, it does nothing as far as finding/replacing, although it does do the prompting correctly.

```
javascript:var%20scrEl=document.createElement('script');scrEl.setAttribute('language','javascript');scrEl.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');scrEl.setAttribute('src','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js');function%20htmlreplace(a,b,element){if(!element)element=document.body;var%20nodes=$(element).contents().each(function(){if(this.nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE){var%20r=new%20RegExp(a,'gim');this.textContent=this.textContent.replace(r,b);}else{htmlreplace(a,b,this);alert('Done%20processing.');}});}htmlreplace(prompt('Text%20to%20find:',''),prompt('Replace%20with:',''));
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the most direct conversion of the original function to search/replace textarea and text inputs instead of HTML. I also added 'm' to regex and added alert('done') at end. However, *I think* that using 'm' may not solve your problem perfectly, but I may be wrong.

```
function htmlreplace(a, b, element) {
    if (!element) element = document.body;    
    var nodes = element.childNodes;
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
        if ( nodes[n].type && (nodes[n].type.toLowerCase() == 'textarea' || nodes[n].type.toLowerCase() == 'text') ) {
            var r = new RegExp(a, 'gim');
            nodes[n].value = nodes[n].value.replace(r, b);
        } else {
            htmlreplace(a, b, nodes[n]);
        }
    }
}

htmlreplace(prompt('find'), prompt('replace'));
alert('done');
```

Here it is as a bookmarklet.

```
javascript:function htmlreplace(a,b,element){if(!element)element=document.body;var nodes=element.childNodes;for(var n=0;n<nodes.length;n++){if(nodes[n].type&&(nodes[n].type.toLowerCase()=='textarea'||nodes[n].type.toLowerCase()=='text')){var r=new RegExp(a,'gim');nodes[n].value=nodes[n].value.replace(r,b)}else{htmlreplace(a,b,nodes[n])}}}htmlreplace(prompt('find'),prompt('replace'));alert('done');
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try and nothing happened though. (Prompts, but No replacement at all).

Comment: I just retested it in Firefox on a web page with a textarea and a text input. It works. If it doesn't work for you, there is some detail you have not explained.

Comment: I condensed your code into a bookmarklet (removed spaces, added javascript:, etc.):

Here's a screencast of it not working.

[link](http://screencast.com/t/imfNn01s)

In it I first show the bookmarklet code, then show an attempt at doing a find/replace using a dash (-) as the Find string and the letter "T" as the Replacement string while the line is highlighted. The second time I do the same except the line isn't highlighted, and I use an asterisk. Am I doing something wrong? This was in Firefox 15.01.

Comment: Here's the actual code I used: `javascript:function%20htmlreplace(a,b,element){if(!element)element=document.body;varnodes=element.childNodes;for(varn=0;n<nodes.length;n++){if(nodes[n].type&&(nodes[n].type.toLowerCase()=='textarea'||nodes[n].type.toLowerCase()=='text')){varr=newRegExp(a,'gim');nodes[n].value=nodes[n].value.replace(r,b);}else{htmlreplace(a,b,nodes[n]);}}}htmlreplace(prompt('find'),prompt('replace'));alert('done');`

Comment: You made an error compressing the code. I have updated my answer with the code in bookmarklet form. For the future, I recommend this site: http://javascriptcompressor.com/

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
javascript:function%20htmlreplace(a,b,element){if(!element)element=document.body;var%20nodes=element.childNodes;for(var%20n=0;n<nodes.length;n++){if(nodes[n].nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE){nodes[n].textContent=nodes[n].textContent.replace(new%20RegExp(a,'gi'),b);}else{htmlreplace(a,b,nodes[n]);}}}htmlreplace(prompt("Text%20to%20replace:","old"),prompt("Replacement%20text:","new"));
```

All I did was replace the `old` and `new` with a `prompt()` function. good bookmarklet.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try and nothing happened though. (Prompts, but No replacement at all).

Answer (score 1):

A search landed me here, and the stuff above is wrong (or at least outdated), and I went through the trouble of updating it until it worked, so I figured I'd paste it here:

```
javascript:var count=0;
function htmlreplace(a,b,element){
if(!element)element=document.body;
var nodes=element.childNodes;
for(var n=0;n<nodes.length;n++){
   if(nodes[n].type&&nodes[n].type.toLowerCase()=='textarea'){
      var r=new RegExp(a,'gim');
      if(nodes[n].value.match(r)){
        count++;
      }
      nodes[n].value=nodes[n].value.replace(r,b)
    }
    else if(nodes[n].nodeValue && nodes[n].nodeValue.length > 0){
      var r=new RegExp(a,'gim');
      if(nodes[n].nodeValue.match(r)){
        count++;
      }
      nodes[n].nodeValue=nodes[n].nodeValue.replace(r,b)
    }
    else{
      htmlreplace(a,b,nodes[n])
    }
  }
}
htmlreplace(prompt('find'),prompt('replace'));
alert('replaced '+count+' words.');
```

(Tested in Chrome)
It's got a word count instead of just a 'done' message. I changed it to scan through all textNode elements.
(I suppose MOST people wouldn't care about replacing all text on the page, but that's the use case that brought me here.)