# Bookmarklet to apply email-style quoting to selection (prefix each line with "> ")

Tags: javascript, replace, selection, bookmarklet

I want to quote the selected text in a textentry field in a form in the traditional email manner, prefixing every line with "`>`".  (It happens to be for Bugzilla today, not that it makes a difference or anything.)

I suspect that it might be possible to adapt the code from [Bookmarklet Help: Creating a Find/Replace Bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769962/bookmarklet-help-creating-a-find-replace-bookmarklet) or its predecessor [Find all instances of 'old' in a webpage and replace each with 'new', using a javascript bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175775/find-all-instances-of-old-in-a-webpage-and-replace-each-with-new-using-a-ja), but I'm not too sure how to apply this to a selection …

(I might be over thinking things, because I keep getting dizzy thinking about selections spanning elements when that's clearly not actually relevent.)

Comment: Not up to providing real answer, but I'll point you in right direction: google 'javascript modify textarea value' and 'javascript get selected text from textarea'. Then its a simple case of `str = '> ' + str.split('\n').join('\n> ')`. Write your solution first in normal js, then convert to a bookmarklet. Google 'bookmarklet creator'.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I don't want to try to write it directly as a bookmarklet :-P.

Comment: Hmm, I'm having trouble with the test harness: clicking on my test button seems to reset my selection before it does `onclick` ...