# Find and replace text within a class attribute on a webpage using a javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, class, replace, find, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a javascript bookmarklet that will find and replace text set as a class with a different text.  For example, I want to find 'shoe' and replace it with 'socks,' see below.

> div class='**shoe**'

and replace it with

> div class='**socks**'

I found this: [Bookmarklet Help: Creating a Find/Replace Bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769962/bookmarklet-help-creating-a-find-replace-bookmarklet).

```
javascript:function%20htmlreplace(a,b,element){if(!element)element=document.body;var%20nodes=element.childNodes;for(var%20n=0;n<nodes.length;n++){if(nodes[n].nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE){nodes[n].textContent=nodes[n].textContent.replace(new%20RegExp(a,'gi'),b);}else{htmlreplace(a,b,nodes[n]);}}}htmlreplace(prompt("Text%20to%20replace:","old"),prompt("Replacement%20text:","new"));
```

But I'm not sure how to manipulate the script to cater my needs above to replace the text within the attribute.

I've no experience with javascripts whatsoever, but I'm trying to understand the language, so please forgive me if I'm messing up the terminology. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 element with that class name, you could use

`javascript:document.getElementByClassName("shoe").className = "socks";`

but for all classes, you could use

`var d=document.getElementByClassName("shoe");for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++){d[i].className="socks";}`