# JavaScript: bookmarklet to show UTF-8 characters correctly

Tags: javascript, utf-8, bookmarklet

I am reading some pages that don't display correctly some UTF-8 characters.
For example [this page](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2013-03-23/travel/31026824_1_yalu-river-north-korea-kim-jong-il) shows **â€“** instead of **en dash (–)**.

Others:

showing **â€™** instead of **’**

showing **â€˜** instead of **‘**  (see [this page](http://www.indianexpress.com/news/ril-ongc-rumoured-as----mystery----bidders-in--8billion-addax-sale/479499))

Is it possible to fix this problem in a bookmarklet?
If yes, then how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution, [being helped by the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175775/find-all-instances-of-old-in-a-webpage-and-replace-each-with-new-using-a-ja):

```
javascript:
function htmlreplace(a, b, element) {    
    if (!element) element = document.body;    
    var nodes = element.childNodes;
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
        if (nodes[n].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var r = new RegExp(a, 'gi');
            nodes[n].textContent = nodes[n].textContent.replace(r, b);
        } else {
            htmlreplace(a, b, nodes[n]);
        }
    }
}
htmlreplace("â€“","–");
htmlreplace("â€™","’");
htmlreplace("â€˜","‘");
htmlreplace("â€œ","“");
htmlreplace("â€ž","„");
```

Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

With a bookmarklet, no. Unfortunately most browsers don't provide a method to change the page encoding with javascript. You may try adding a meta tag to affect the encoding but this may not work with all browsers (google "meta tag encoding"). This is primarily a server issue - the web server sent the wrong encoding header for the page.

However, if you want a menu item that you can invoke from the browser to change the encoding (which is basically what a bookmarklet is anyway) you can simply invoke the encoding menu and change it to UTF-8. On IE8 it's `Page->Encoding->UTF8`, on Chrome it's `Menu->Tools->Encoding->UTF8`. Google around for other browsers.

Comment: Maybe you can't change the encoding but you can simply replace text.