# Find, Change multiple instances of text on page is Slow and Unresponsive, but Works

Tags: javascript

Edit: StackOverFlow is replacing Japanese Characters with translations upon saving my question.

This makes it look like I'm replacing the same text, with the same text.

The first item(of the dupes, below) should be Japanese text.

Using the scripts described here:

[Find all instances of 'old' in a webpage and replace each with 'new', using a javascript bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175775/find-all-instances-of-old-in-a-webpage-and-replace-each-with-new-using-a-ja)

I've gone about trying to translate Yahoo Japan Auction pages
(yes, i know translation engines exist, but I have my reasons...)

example page:

http://auctions.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?auccat=&p=bose&tab_ex=commerce&ei=UTF-8&fr=bzr-prop

Have tried a couple scripts and While the scripts work, I must wait and click the "Unresponsive Script" a couple of times before the changes occur (10-20 seconds)

While I'm certain my implementation is buggy, also uncertain how to proceed.
The script can contain over 200 change items.
These below are culled for space considerations.

Version 1 Script:

```
function newTheOlds(node) {
    node = node || document.body;
    if(node.nodeType == 3) {
        // Text node
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.split('Car,Bike').join('Car,Bike');
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.split('Current $').join('Current $');
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.split('Buy it Now').join('Buy it Now');
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.split('Bid').join('Bid');
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.split('Remaining Time').join('Remaining Time');
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.split('Popular-Newest').join('Popular-Newest');
    } else {
        var nodes = node.childNodes;
        if(nodes) {
            var i = nodes.length;
            while(i--) newTheOlds(nodes[i]);
        }
    }
}

newTheOlds();
```

Version 2 Script:

```
function htmlreplace(a, b, element) {    
    if (!element) element = document.body;    
    var nodes = element.childNodes;
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
        if (nodes[n].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var r = new RegExp(a, 'gi');
            nodes[n].textContent = nodes[n].textContent.replace(r, b);
        } else {
            htmlreplace(a, b, nodes[n]);
        }
    }
}


    htmlreplace('Car,Bike', 'Car,Bike');
    htmlreplace('Current $', 'Current $');
    htmlreplace('Buy it Now', 'Buy it Now');
    htmlreplace('Bid', 'Bid');
    htmlreplace('Remaining Time', 'Remaining Time');
    htmlreplace('Popular-Newest', 'Popular-Newest');
    htmlreplace('Display', 'Display');
    htmlreplace('Music', 'Music');
    htmlreplace('Hobby', 'Hobby');
    htmlreplace('Books/Mags', 'Books/Mags');
    htmlreplace('Antiques', 'Antiques');
    htmlreplace('Comics/Anime', 'Comics/Anime');
    htmlreplace('Movie/Video', 'Movie/Video');
    htmlreplace('Computers', 'Computers');
    htmlreplace('Others', 'Others');
```

Should I be trying another technique?

Thanks,
Woody

Answer (score 0):

> While I'm certain my implementation is buggy, also uncertain how to proceed.

- Replace multiple `node.nodeValue =` an assignment to a documentFragment
- Move the strings in the multiple `htmlreplace` calls into a key/value object literal
- Replace the loop with an `Array.prototype.map` call over the `childNodes` of the documentFragment
- Replace matches using a replacer callback which references the object literal

**References**

- [createDocumentFragment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536387)
- [DOM documentFragments](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/)
- [Alternatives to innerHTML](http://slayeroffice.com/articles/innerHTML_alternatives/)
- [The tiny table sorter - or - you can write LINQ in JavaScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/08/19/10442582.aspx)